# When should i use async/await in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, asynchronous

**Meta Context:**

I'm building an api using [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Since it's an asynchronous framework, I have to use async to define handlers. Example:

```
async def index_handler(request):
    return web.Response(text="Hello, world")

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_route("GET", "/", index_handler)
```

**Code Context:**

During development, I found myself in a situation where i have nested function calls like so:

```
def bar():
    return "Hi"

async def foo():
    return bar()

await foo()
```

When I was thinking about performance, I didn't know whether or not I should do these nested functions all async as well. Example:

```
async def bar()
    return "Hi"

async def foo():
    return await bar()

await foo()
```

**Question:**

What is the best way to do nested function calls to optimize performance?  Always use async/await or always use sync? Does this makes a difference?

Comment: Processes that are naturally asynchronous should be done with `async`. Eg: waiting for any kind of IO. In your case it's the opposite: your "async-everywhere" solution is slower, since `async` does not come for free. That's another reason why every performance optimisation should come with before-after benchmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your case you dont need to async everything unless you have code that could potentially block things for example:

```
def bar():
    """This function is not async because there is no need to."""
    return "Hi"

async def foo():
    return bar()

await foo()
```

But if your function bar for examples sleeps or do some async functions inside, then you should async the function

```
async def bar():
    """This function needs to be async because there 
    are operations that potentially could block"""
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return "Hi"

async def foo():
    return bar()

await foo()
```

So for summarize, if you are using async operations you need to have a very clear idea of how your program runs and what it is doing in order to avoid to put async everywhere.